# How many non-isomorphic binary trees are there with N leaves?

Tags: tree, binary-tree

I'm interested in find out how many "shapes" are there for a binary tree with N leaves.  I.e., disregarding the content of the leaves, and disregarding the order of the nodes at each level, how many different ways can such a tree be drawn?

In the following notation, I denote simply the depth of nodes by an integer.   I consider the tree (1 (2 2)) equivalent to ((2 2) 1) because they only differ by the order of the two level-1 nodes.

When I try to count the different trees by hand, the number does not seem to grow explosively, at least up to 7 leaves.   However, I have the sense that it will soon explode.

E.g.
There is 1 with 2 leaves (1 1). 
There is 1 with 3 leaves (1 (2 2)).
There are 2 with 4 leaves

> ```
> (1 (2 (3 3)))
> ((2 2) (2 2))
> ```

There are 3 with 5 leaves

> ```
> (1 (2 (3 (4 4))))
> (1 ((3 3) (3 3))) 
> ((2 2) (2 (3 3)))
> ```

There are 6 with 6 leaves

> ```
> (1 (2 (3 (4 (5 5)))))
> (1 (2 ((4 4) (4 4))))
> (1 ((3 3) (3 (4 4))))
> ((2 2) (2 (3 (4 4))))
> ((2 2) ((3 3) (3 3)))
> ((2 (3 3)) (2 (3 3)))
> ```

I count 11 with 7 leaves.

> ```
> (1 (2 (3 (4 (5 (6 6))))))
> (1 (2 (3 ((5 5) (5 5)))))
> (1 (2 ((4 4) (4 (5 5)))))
> (1 ((3 3) (3 (4 (5 5)))))
> (1 ((3 3) ((4 4) (4 4))))
> (1 ((3 (4 4)) (3 (4 4))))
> ((2 2) (2 (3 (4 (5 5)))))
> ((2 2) (2 ((4 4) (4 4))))
> ((2 2) ((3 3) (3 (4 4))))
> ((2 (3 3)) (2 (3 (4 4))))
> ((2 (3 3)) ((3 3) (3 3)))
> ```

Comment: It appears to be the half catalan numbers. https://oeis.org/A000992